# Virtual Keyboard for Kubuntu 22.04, preferably suporting wayland

Tags: kubuntu, wayland, tablet, onscreen-keyboard

I recently received my [GPD Pocket 3](https://gpd.hk/gpdpocket3). This is a convertible netbook/tablet device that comes shipped with win 11. As [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) is my OS of choice, I installed Kubuntu 22.04, with some additional [scripts](https://github.com/wimpysworld/umpc-ubuntu) from [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

Under X11 automatic screen rotation does not work. It works however under Wayland.

One important thing missing is a virtual keyboard. While under x11 KDE Settings do not have such a setting, under wayland there is such a setting but it offers only none as a choice.
I installed onboard but it does not adjust the size when rotated, does not automatically pop-up, does not resize the windows you want to enter text into (thereby covering the text field) and is not a very good experience under KDE/x11 (though it is arguably a good keyboard on Gnome). Moreover, it crashes on Wayland.

Considering that plasma mobile has a working virtual keyboard, I expected this to be trivial in KDE. But I am obviously missing something.

Any ideas?

PS: Ideally I would like something that also supports a Greek layout.
Tested instructions on compiling [maliit](https://maliit.github.io/) on 22.04 would be an acceptable answer.
There is [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1973293) related bug, that has no response or confirmation.

Comment: someone in the comments of [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/lm2qjl/plasma_521_released_and_the_virtual_keyboard_is/)  has a method for installing maliit keyboard that might work for you

Comment: @Esther Thanks for the link. Though installing is probably the wrong term when on (K)Ubuntu. The commenter had manjaro. On Kubuntu I would have to compile, which according to what I have read till now is not trivial.